# Is any way to debug Asp.net projects to new Visual Studio 2015 Emulator for Android?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

As Microsoft provided new emulator for Android in Visual Studio 2015. Is any way to run, test and debug an `asp.net` projects in the new emulator?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you just access the site now using the emulator?

Comment: @mason, You could run and debug a local asp.net project in Windows Phone Emulator with full debugging features like profiling or browser link. I mean is any way to same things with the android emulator to?

Comment: You still didn't answer my question.

Comment: @mason, I can open the site on the emulator by typing physical machine's IP address. And site is working fine. But I can not use browser link for example. Also I need to bind my IP address and add an firewall exception to each project.

Comment: Why doesn't browser link work? Try checking the debug console in the browser to see if there's a client side error. And of course, make sure browser link is enabled in VS.

Comment: @mason, Browser link is enabled and working with other browsers. But in the emulator dose not works. Also how can I debug JS in the emulator?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to debug directly from an ASP.net project to the Android emulator. However, you can start the emulator by going to Tools > "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" and hitting the play button on one of the device profiles.

Then, start the web app project in Visual Studio and navigate to the IP in the emulator. To do this, you need to proxy emulator network traffic through the host machine. You may also need to configure IIS Express to allow access via that IP address and configure the firewall to let HTTP traffic through on that port. There's some advice for how to do these in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/05/06/using-fiddler-to-monitor-network-traffic-from-the-vs-emulator-for-android.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I had done those configuration before. I searched an easy and fast method to do this stuff. Also a easy way to direct debug an asp.net project on the emulator. Maybe it's time to develop an extension this ;)